# 2001 f150 suspension package

Tags: suspension, steering, f-150, stability

Just replaced the suspension package on a 2001 F150.
OEM parts.

The issue I'm having is that when I go above 50mph and hit a bump/pot hole, there's a significant amount of jarring that occurs.
Thoughts on what adjustment needs to be made?

I replaced the upper control arm & ball joint, lower ball joint, tie rods (both ends) and linkage arm links.  Both sides.

Comment: You sure this just isn't how it's supposed to be behaving? Maybe you could explain better what you mean by "jarring". Also, the size of the hole/bump is probably relevant as well.

Comment: Context: I live in Minnesota so our roads are in crummy condition and have to be re-done every 2-3 years.

The jarring seems abnormal in that if I go over a large highway seam or bridge joint the steering wheel will pull significantly in one direction or the other.

Comment: Did you mess with the power steering at all? Like with doing the tie rods

Comment: Did you do the work on your truck? If so, did you wait until the vehicle was on the ground before you torqued everything? Bushings will get preload on them if you torque then with the suspension fully unloaded. This may be causing your driving issues.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes, i did do the work myself.  But tie rods torqued after load.  Control arm and ball joints done preload.   Will the torque be too high or too low if torqued preload?

Comment: Torque on the bolts isn't the problem, the problem is preload on the control arm bushings. Since they are made of rubber, they will deformed and provide a certain amount of "spring" to the arm if you tighten their bolts before the vehicle is on the ground. If this isn't remedied soon, this will start tearing the rubber and all the hard work is down the tubes. This could be affecting the handling of the truck. The ball joints and tie rod ends don't matter as they are a joint which will rotate after they are tightened.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 you are a champ.  I'll make the adjustment.